# ¿Como calcular el MCM en python?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo es mi primer semestre y de tarea tengo el calcular el MCM en Python pero en mi codigo me aparece error y no se como arreglarlo alguien podria decirme como arreglar mi codigo?

```
A =int(input())
B =int(input())
C = B

while(C!= 0):
    C= A%B
    A = B
    B = C 
    X = (A*B)/B
print(X)
```

Comment: Cual es el error que te sale??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El máximo común divisor, sonará a tontería pero es el número más alto que divide exactamente a todos los números, y un número está exactamente dividido cuando su resto es 0, o sea que no sobra nada, 4 entre 2 es 2, 2 para mi y 2 para ti, no sobra nada, resto 0.

vale.

con eso en la cabeza, presentamos el siguiente ejemplo: que será calcular el máximo común divisor de 3 números los cuales se los pediremos al usuario.

```
num1 = int(input('Primer número: )
num2 = int(input('Segundo número: )
num3 = int(input('Tercer número: )
```

Un número que divida exactamente a esos números tiene que ser menor o igual al menor de esos números, quiero decir, si por ejemplo los números son 12, 6 y 4, el número que divide exactamente a esos 3 números no puede ser 6, porque 4 no puede ser repartido exactamente entre 6 o entre 12 (pero ojalá)

sabiendo eso, identificaremos al número máximo, al mínimo y al mediano.
para no hacer una cadena inmensa de "if" y evaluar en plan, si este número es más grande que este otro y este otro, entonces este número es el máximo... (porque sería poco fastidioso)

usaremos la funcion max() y también la min() (encuentra el máximo y el mínimo respectivamente

```
maxi = max(num1, num2, num3)
mini = min(num1, num2, num3)
```

para encontrar al mediano pues tendrémos que evaluar un poquito creo yo... tal que así

```
if maxi != num1 and mini != num1:
        medi = num1
if maxi != num2 and mini != num2:
        medi = num2
if maxi != num3 and mini != num3:
        medi = num3
```

vale perfe.

ahora necesitamos ir recorriendo todos los números desde el minimo hasta 1, descendentemente, porque en cuanto encontremos a uno que sea capaz de dividirlo exactamente a los 3, ese será el máximo común divisor, los demás no nos importan.

```
mcd = False
i = mini

while not mcd and i >=1:
     if mini % i == 0 and medi % i == 0 and maxi % i == 0:
            mcd = True
            print(i)
     else:
          i -= 1
```

y listo, podría explicar ésta última parte, pero si la analizas la entenderás, hasta donde yo sé, así lo haría yo, al menos, hasta donde yo sé hasta ahora jaja

Answer (score 9):

Por lo que veo creo que estas intentando obtener el M.C.D (máximo común divisor) mediante el [algoritmo de Euclides](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Euclides) y después usarlo para calcular el M.C.M (mínimo común multiplo) dado que:

> M.C.M(A, B) = (A * B) / M.C.D(A, B)

Tal y como tienes tu código te sale un error por división entre 0:

> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

ya que llega un momento en que B vale 0 y produce un error en la linea:

```
X = (A*B)/B
```

Esta linea es para calcular el M.C.M usando el M.C.D y no pertenece por tanto al algoritmo de Euclides por lo que debe estar **fuera** del ciclo while:

Por otro lado el algoritmo requiere saber cuál es el número menor por lo que es oportuno comprobar esto antes y asignar adecuadamente cada valor. El código podria quedar así:

```
num1 =int(input())
num2 =int(input())

A = max(num1, num2)
B = min(num1, num2)

while B:
    mcd = B
    B = A % B
    A = mcd
mcm =  (num1 * num2) // mcd

print('El M.C,D de {0} y {1} es {2}'.format(num1, num2, mcd))
print('El M.C.D de {0} y {1} es {2}'.format(num1, num2, mcm))
```

Esto seria un ejemplo de ejecución:

```
54
90
El M.C,D de 54 y 90 es 18
El M.C.D de 54 y 90 es 270
```

[min()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) y [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) son dos funciones preconstruidas de Python que retornan el mínimo y máximo valor de un iterable respectivamente, si no quieres usarlas puedes sustituir esas dos lineas por algo como:

```
if num1 > num2:
    A = num1
    B = num2
else:
    A = num2
    B = num1
```

**Aclaración**: Como no especificas que versión de Python usas, he usado la divisón entera `//` y no `/` a la hora de calcular el M.C.M usando el M.C.D porque en Python 3 `/` retorna un `float` y no un `int` como en Python 2.